# needing to sign in to use custom API in google cloud

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

Hi there I created a custom API in google cloud but when I try to access the API it only gives me the google thing for signing into google cloud console

script for access API:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// Load the service account key file
const serviceAccountKey = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

// Configure Axios to use Google authentication
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  credentials: serviceAccountKey,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
});
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${auth.getAccessToken().then(response => response.token)}`;

// Define the URL of your API endpoint
const apiUrl = 'https://3002-cs-105746203933-default.cs-us-east1-vpcf.cloudshell.dev/api/userids/Dan';

// Make a GET request to the API endpoint
axios.get(apiUrl)
  .then(response => {
    // Handle successful response
    console.log('Response:', response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle error
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  });
```

the actual api code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;

// Connect to MongoDB database
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.aviwp.mongodb.net/CarboCredit");
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});

// Define a schema for the userids "table" (sub-collection)
const userIdsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // Define the fields relevant to the userids "table"
  // For example:
  id: Number,
  // Other fields...
});

// Define a model based on the schema
const UserIds = mongoose.model("CarboCredit", userIdsSchema, "userids");


const app = express();

app.get("/api/userids/:userId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Get the userId from request parameters
    const { userId } = req.params;

    // Find a document in UserIds sub-collection with the given userId
    const user = await UserIds.findOne({username: userId});

    // If no document found with the given userId
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    // Document found, return it as JSON response
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error fetching user:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

the code gives me the correct output when I access it inside google cloud vm but I want to access it in another google cloud VM it gives me a link to log into google cloud VM and when I tried to through post mate it was the same issue and I when I try to login it gives me a 400 error I was wondering if this could be bypassed or dissabled somehow

Comment: auth.getAccessToken() returns a `promise`.